# Get data from Django model and display in a html table using AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, django

I've searched and implemented so many different ways to display a html table, using AJAX, from a JsonResponse (Django) - but to no avail.

Currently, the furthest I've gotten is a response to the network console:

```
{"products": "[{\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Bag\", \"description\": \"Carries items conspicuously \", \"price\": \"10.99\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 3, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"iPhone 8 Plus\", \"description\": \"a mobile device from Apple\", \"price\": \"850.00\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 8, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Shoes\", \"description\": \"For your feet\", \"price\": \"49.50\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 9, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Gloves\", \"description\": \"For your hands\", \"price\": \"2.99\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 10, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Blanket\", \"description\": \"Keep warm\", \"price\": \"13.79\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 11, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Gown\", \"description\": \"Sleep time\", \"price\": \"25.99\"}}]"}
```

but I want this dictionary to display on my html table via ajax

My django model looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100000)
```

my django view:

```
def product_list(request):

    productData = serializers.serialize("json", Product.objects.all())
    return JsonResponse({"products": productData})
```

my html page body:

```
<body style='text-align:center'>
<table class="table table-striped" id="product-table">
    <thead class="thead-dark"><th>Item<th>Description<th>Price</th><th></th></thead>


    <tr>
        <form id="add-product">{% csrf_token %}
            <td><a><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="newProductName" placeholder="Product name"></a></td>
            <td><a><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="newProductDesc" placeholder="Product description"></a></td>
            <td><a><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="newProductPrice" placeholder="£--.--"></a></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="newProductSubmit">add</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>

</table>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and my ajax function to get the jsonresponse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'products/getProducts/',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Got data!")
            jData = JSON.parse(data)
            alert("got json products!");
        }
    });
});
```

with the ajax, I am aware I'm missing something to convert the data to html and append to my table, but when I tried this it simply didn't add anything

Comment: Not fully clear that you want to display the response data in the Form input fields or in a table?

Comment: @zollie in a table, the form is a separate part

Comment: OK, I am checking it and get back to you.

Comment: You have double-encoded your data. You shouldn't put the JSON result from serialize into another dict which itself is serialized by JsonResponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just give you an example of how a table can be created in HTML from the javascript JSON string data what you provided above:

```
<div>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#dfdfdf" width="40%" align="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Name</th>
        <th width="50%">Description</th>
        <th width="12%">price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
</table>
</div>

<style>      
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var newProducts = {"products": "[{\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Bag\", \"description\": \"Carries items conspicuously \", \"price\": \"10.99\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 3, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"iPhone 8 Plus\", \"description\": \"a mobile device from Apple\", \"price\": \"850.00\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 8, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Shoes\", \"description\": \"For your feet\", \"price\": \"49.50\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 9, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Gloves\", \"description\": \"For your hands\", \"price\": \"2.99\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 10, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Blanket\", \"description\": \"Keep warm\", \"price\": \"13.79\"}}, {\"model\": \"products.product\", \"pk\": 11, \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Gown\", \"description\": \"Sleep time\", \"price\": \"25.99\"}}]"};    

var mainObj = JSON.parse(newProducts.products); // I created an object from the json response

// you can iterate over the javascript Object

var k = '<tbody>'

    for(i = 0;i < mainObj.length; i++){             
        k+= '<tr>';
        k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["name"] + '</td>';
        k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["description"] + '</td>';
        k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["price"] + '</td>';
        k+= '</tr>';
    }
    k+='</tbody>';
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;

</script>
```

And this is a simple table result of the above code:

[image: HTML table from json data response]

I hope this can show you some direction. You can of course style the table (or create the table other ways) and you can access all of the other data studying and using this example.

So, you should just extend your Ajax with calling the added javascript function at **success:** which I placed in to your jQuery/javasript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'products/getProducts/',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Got data!")
            jData = JSON.parse(data)
            alert("got json products!");
            tableFromResponse(jData);
        }
    });
});

function tableFromResponse(responseData) {

        var mainObj = JSON.parse(responseData.products);

        var k = '<tbody>'

        for(i = 0;i < mainObj.length; i++){

            k+= '<tr>';
            k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["name"] + '</td>';
            k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["description"] + '</td>';
            k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["fields"]["price"] + '</td>';
            k+= '</tr>';
        }
        k+='</tbody>';
        document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
}
```

(of course, the lot of json.parse step could be left out from the code if it's causing trouble. Since I wrote the code without real response data from Django in this case).