# how to send notification for some specific objects django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i want to add a function to my project to return json data and display it in the main template (base.html) using ajax , this is my function

```
@login_required
def alerts(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        sender = Post.objects.filter(active=False)
        return JsonResponse(sender)
```

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #others
```

and this is my base.html

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.btn-click').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              url:'/ajax/alerts/',
              type:'get',
              success:function(data){
                document.getElementById('alerts').append(data.title)

              }

          })
      })
  })
```

```html
        <div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }">
          <button @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen"
            class="relative z-10 block rounded-md text-black p-2 focus:outline-none btn-click">
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            <!-- <img src="icon/bell.svg" class="w-5"  alt=""> -->
          </button>
      
          <div x-show="dropdownOpen"
            class="absolute left-2 top-10 text-right py-2 w-59 grayBG rounded-md shadow-xl z-20 h-48 overflow-y-scroll ">

            <p class="whiteCOLOR text-center border-b border-red-500 p-2" id="alerts"></p>
      
      
          </div>
        </div>
```

and my urls.py

```
path('ajax/alerts', alerts,name='alerts'),
```

but it shows nothing !?
and in the console log returns

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/alerts/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

i want to display those posts which not accepted in an alert , thank you ..

Comment: Check your browser console if there are any errors. Also, try to print the JsonResponse and see if it actually returns anything.

Comment: it return `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/alerts/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: So, the problem is with your view logic. Try to see what error occurs,it should display in your Django server log.

Comment: it works for  `sender = {'a':'b'}` but the problem in the for loop i think

Comment: What error is returned from Django when the ajax call is made?

Comment: there is no error , all works , but in  the console shows `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231922/discussion-between-oluwakayode-and-hunar-mohammed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from Django model and display in a html table using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249365/get-data-from-django-model-and-display-in-a-html-table-using-ajax)

Comment: @rob it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` and FYI the script is at the end of the file